# Looping in Time Python

Tags: python

I'm new in python programming. I have a Question. I want to save every input data (raw data to list) every 15 minutes. after 15 minutes the list wil be delete and write input data again.can anyone help me please?thank you for your kindness.

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory

def WriteListtoCSV (data):
    with open ('tesdata.csv','a') as csvfile:
        writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
        for val in data:
            writer.writerow([val])

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
        else:
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

        # echo back message verbatim
        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

        mins = 0
        data_nilai = [ ]
        while mins != 60: #change value with seconds
            data_nilai.append(payload.decode('utf8'))
            time.sleep(1) 
            mins+=1

        WriteListtoCSV(data_nilai)
        #ClearCSV()

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import csv
    import time


    from twisted.python import log
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://192.168.1.23:9000", debug=False)
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    # factory.setProtocolOptions(maxConnections=2)

    reactor.listenTCP(9000, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

my focus is only onMessage

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here we can try to fix your code if it's not working but we are not going to write the code for you. You must try to write the code first, then we can help you.

Comment: Please post some trial code and together we can take it forward :)

Comment: `raw_input`, `time` and `using lists in python` could be your pointers to start with.

Comment: post that code in the question..It might help more :)

Comment: What else are you planning to do with that data?

Comment: I want to wrie in CSV file every 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Following is Algo with small code.

**Algo**:

1. Set detail file path where we are saving data.
2. Get Input from the user and process to create list.
3. Save data to file.
4. Wait for some time.
5. Delete File.

**Code**:

```
import pickle
import time
import os

detail_file = "/tmp/test.txt"
while(1):
    # Get input from User and split to List.
    user_input = raw_input("Enter item of the list separated by comma:")
    user_input = user_input.split(",") 
    print "User List:- ", user_input

    #- Save process, We can save your data i.e. list into file or database or any where
    with open(detail_file, "wb") as fp:
        pickle.dump(user_input, fp)

    # Wait for 15 minutes.
    time.sleep(900)  # 15 * 60  = 900 

    # delete Save details.
    os.remove(detail_file)
```

**Note**:

Use `input()` to get user information for **Python 3.x**

Use `raw_input()` to get user information for **Python 2.x**

**[Edit 1]**

**Crontab**

Ref: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/

Ref: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm

OS: CentOS

To edit the crontab, use this command:

```
crontab -e

*/15 * * * * python /tmp/script.py
```

where crontab entry structure is:

```
m h  dom mon dow   command
```

Comment: thank you. I mean. I only send data if time over 15 minute, not give delay 15 minutes.

Comment: Then need to set `cron tab` to run send script or  run py file always and which call your script after every 15 minutes.

Comment: can you give example using `cron tab` please

Comment: Added crontab details in answer, you can check this and let me know if you need more details